# Is there a way for one player to have a solo but the rest of the instrument keep playing?

Tags: composition, engraving, solos, accompaniment, pizzicato

I'm writing a piece where there is like a bass line which is made up of all 5 string section parts (orchestra) that each have a similar rhythm, and that all together makes a cool sound.

I want to add a sort of melody that bounces around the ensemble, but only one player per section plays. I feel like making it divisi might work, but that would be for multiple players.  It is also a pizzicato part and I'm not sure if there is a way to have divisi, with the top part pizz and the bottom part arco.

For reference, this is what all five parts look like together:
[image: Score for 1st and 2nd violins, viola, cello, and contrabass]

I want to add pizz for the notes "E" and "F" for violin parts, and notes "A" and "G" for cello with the first note being a grace note for the second which will be a quarter note thrown in, in a couple spots.

I'm aware I could just add another part and have it only be given to one player, but that is a lot more paper for just a few notes.

Comment: So what is the question you are asking?

Comment: I think the question is how to notate two parts (solo player and the rest of the section) on one staff.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the sections with a soloist should split into two staves for the solo.  Connect these staves with a thin margin bracket.  Mark the solo staff *solo*, and the other staff *gli altri* (the others).  These extra staves collapse away when the solo is over, mark this with *tutti* (everyone).

It looks neatest when the splitting and merging coincides with a system break (line break/page break).

NB-1: "Viola" is a feminine noun in Italian, so *sola* and *le altre* are used for this part instead.
NB-2: If you want say 2 soloist playing the same part, use the plural *soli* e.g. *2 soli*, (*2 sole* for violas).

If each of the string sections has the solo at the same time, it should look something like this:

[image: Each of the five string sections' staves splitting into a "solo" staff and "gli altri" staff at a page break, and joining again the next page break with "tutti."]

Then you can add *pizz.* and *arco* to the respective staves.

Don't worry about taking a little extra paper; it's more important that the music is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can write divisi and mark the "melody" parts as "solo pizz."